# Can I get reference of an application in a class without explicitly passing it as argument to the class in Play framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.6

I have created a `Helper` class. It has a method which creates a token

```
class HelperMethods{
def createUserToken(userId:UUID, userKey:UserKeys, isSignUp:Boolean):UserToken = {
      UserToken(UUID.randomUUID(), userId, userKey, new DateTime().plusHours(12), isSignUp) 
  }
}
```

I want to pick the value `12` from a config file. While I can pass the instance of `configuration` to `HelperMethods` class, it is possible to get the reference of the application (and thus the configuration) without explicitly passing it as the argument?

I am using compile time injection

Comment: You may want to try this https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaConfig#ConfigLoader

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
val restConfig = ConfigFactory.load("rest.conf") //your conf file
val pageSize = restConfig.getInt("pagesize") //the value you want from conf file
```